# Паттер admin/ используется urls.py из папки с приложением для проекта

Tags: django

Когда я перехожу на `128.0.0.1:8000/admin`, `/admin` использует `cutter/urls.py` (cutter это приложение). Но должен использовать `cut_and_go/urls.py` (cut_and_go это имя проекта). И получается, он не может перейти, потому что старается использовать паттерн из `cutter/urls.py`, который служит для редиректа с помощью коротких ссылок на другой сайт.
**cut_and_go/urls.py:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('cutter.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

**cutter/urls.py:**

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.input_form), # форма для ввода длинного адреса, который нужно сократить
    path('<str:getted_short_url>/', views.redirect_view) # getted_short_url это переменная, которая передается в функцию redirect_view, а в этой функции переменная передается на метод класса URL, который находит длинную (несокращенную) ссылку, на которую redirect_view и переводит.
]
```

Comment: Если я комментирую path('<str:getted_short_url>/', views.redirect_view), то я спокойно могу перейти по /admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поменяйте местами

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('cutter.urls')),
]
```

Почему - я уже описал [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1288487/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC-urls-py)

Comment: Спасибо вам. Я чтобы поменять название проэкта его пересоздал и использовал ровно тот же код, как и в проэкте со старым название. И у меня там все работало. странно, но я понял почему там правильнее

Comment: может добавили в у url префикс. пожалуйста